# Do adding value/Child events to a around 15 firebase objects cause heap size increments?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am working on an application and I need to load all the user data when he logs in.

So i am listening to multiple firebase references with the value and child event listeners  and updating the local database in my app.

Lately ive noticed that when i use a 15 or more listener(approximately) i get heap size growth alerts in the logcat while waiting for valueEvents and ChildEvents.

Did it happened to someone here? I am not sure if my code is not responsive or not using firebase right. Maybe that theres a bug in the firebase API.

When i comment on of the lines that assign listener to the reference it is working pretty well.

I am also saving all those listeners in a list so i could remove them when i am finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listeners themselves are relatively cheap to add and should not cause significant heap growth. However, the data that is pulled down to the device as a result of adding the listener can be large and trigger heap growth warnings.

The Firebase SDK will use memory proportional to the amount of data returned by your listeners. So, if your listener is pulling down a large object, it will use more memory. Small objects will use less.

One thing to try is to fetch the same data via curl (try .toString() on the Firebase ref to get the URL) and see how much data is returned. If it is significantly more than you were expecting, you may need to tailor your data layout or the queries you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
Each listener that is attached pull about 10kb, That doesn't sound like much. Any other known issue that can cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: No known issues causing this. There is some overhead to storing Firebase data, since the SDK keeps an internal cache. If you remove the listeners, does the heap return to the expected size, after garbage collection?

Comment: Removing them didn't help, The problem was that i tried to load 2MB of data, After removing some unnecessary data everything was OK and the heap did not grow.

Comment: Cool. Glad to hear it.