# Real time value listener for shared data in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, share

Originally, I have the following setting:

```
folder:{
 uid1:{
  f1:{}
  f2:{}
 }
}
```

and I am able to listen the value of that uid by:

```
ref('/folder/uid').on('value', functon ....
```

The security rule can be simply like this:

```
"folders": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
  }
},
```

But now I have to do **folder sharing** and planning to do the followings:

```
user:{
 uid1:{
  folderAccessRight:{
  read: {fid1:true}
  write: {fid1:true}
  }
 }
}

folder:{
 fid1:{}
 fid2:{}
}
```

The security rule can be set to check if the $fid exist on the user's folderAccessRight JSON. However, since **security rule cannot be a filter**, I can no longer listen on the top level folder ref ('/folder').

If I add a separate value listener on different folders and **the user has N folders**, I need **N listeners**.

Questions:

- Will having **multiple listeners harm the performance?**
- **Is there any better way** to organize the data & listen the data in real time?

Comment: I started writing an answer (I left it as a stub for now) and then realized that I don't understand you data model well enough. Can you show an operation that you're having problems implementing?

Comment: Having multiple listeners is not a problem, as long as you keep the number reasonable. What is reasonable depends on your app, but in general: listen only for data that is showing on your screen. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/37635733/, http://stackoverflow.com/q/24558317/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I haven't started the transformation yet, my code is still doing the original stuff: listening on the ref 'folder/uid1', I am just exploring how to share data among different users. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

With your current data structure, you've secured access to the folders. Each user can now only access the folders that they own or that they've been granted access to.

The problem seems to be that you have no way to *list* the folders that a user has access to.

As usual when using Firebase (and most other NoSQL storage systems) the solution is to add the data that you need for that to your model. In your case that means that you add a list of folders for each user: